# Error code for tool subset_taxa; Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, phyloseq

I load .biom data into R using library phyloseq.

```
Data2020 <- import_biom("XXX")
mapfile2020 <- import_qiime_sample_data("XXX")
tree <- read_tree("XXX")

mydata <- merge_phyloseq(Data2020, mapfile2020, tree)
colnames(tax_table(mydata)) <- c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus", "Species") 

ps <- mydata 
ps1 <- subset_taxa(ps, Phylum != "NA")
```

Subset to the data I want.

```
WRB_data <- subset_samples(ps1, Site=="WRB")
```

Then Try to Subset by a taxa.

```
WRB_data2 <- subset_taxa(WRB_data, Phylum=="Acidobacteria")
```

Always results in this error. Please Help!?

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. Please, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to verify without data, but it looks like there is no taxa of the phylum Acidobacteria in `WRB_data`.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar problem, and overcame it by making sure this part is correctly labeled

```
(Phylum=="Acidobacteria")
```